# Inconsistent Display Color in Charging and non-charging state

Tags: laptop, colors, display-settings, charging, laptop-display

I bought the Asus ROG Zephyrus G14 couple of weeks ago and I use it for work so much that I have to charge it twice a day. The problem is that I have noticed a sudden improvement in the Color of the screen as soon as I supply plug in the charger. I want to make it cosistent so that it doesn't affect my eyes more than its already doing.

By Improvement in Color I mean the sharpness and contrast of the display and not the brightness. I mean its a much better display to look at while the laptop is charging.

I looked into advanced power settings but couldn't find anything that could make the color more consistent.

So to sumarize my question, "How do I make the display to show consistent colors accross both, charging and non-charging states?"

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for so many days, I got the answer on Reddit. Just to give them a credit, I am posting the link.

[Screen dimming while on battery on Asus Zephyrus G14](https://www.reddit.com/r/ZephyrusG14/comments/hrz47j/how_to_stop_my_brightness_going_down_when_on/)